# Trying to add using a multiple in a for statement

Tags: java

I'm trying to change the x into a pyramid of multiples. Ex. if the multiple was 2 it would add by 2s going down. I kept getting multiples that would mess up and swap around when I tried and was wondering if anyone would be kind enough to help!
This is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main 
{
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
   int rows=0;
   int multiple=0;
   int x=0;

   Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("Input Rows to Generate: ");
   rows = scan.nextInt();
   System.out.println("Input Multiple to Count by: ");
   multiple = scan.nextInt();
   System.out.println();

   for (int i = 1; i<=rows; i++)
   {
    for (int j = 1; j<=i; j++)
    {
      System.out.print("x");
    }
    System.out.println();
   } 
  }
}
```

ex.
Enter the number of rows:

5

Enter the multiple to count by:

1

0

1          2

3          4          5

6          7          8          9

10        11        12        13        14

Comment: Can you give an example of output for a specific input?

Comment: I just added it to the bottom :)

Comment: For starters, `System.out.print("x")` serves no purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main 
{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  int rows=0;
  int multiple=0;
  int x=0;

  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Input Rows to Generate: ");
  rows = scan.nextInt();
  System.out.println("Input Multiple to Count by: ");
  multiple = scan.nextInt();
  System.out.println();
  int n = 0;
  for (int i = 1; i <= rows; i++){
    for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++){
      System.out.print(multiple * n + " ");
      n++;
    }
    System.out.println();
  } 

 } 
}
```

For `rows = 5` and `multiple = 1` the output will be:

```
0 
1 2 
3 4 5 
6 7 8 9 
10 11 12 13 14
```

Also, for `rows = 5` and `multiple = 2` the output will be:

```
0 
2 4 
6 8 10 
12 14 16 18 
20 22 24 26 28
```

Comment: `5 3 4`? That's not the expected output.